# python dictionary counting how many times a word occurs and linking to the word in a dictionary

Tags: python-2.7

How can I get the program to read through a list of words and add them to a dictionary with the number of times they occur (I have them in a list named `w` to call on):

```
words = {}
for ws in w:
  if ws not in words:
    words[ws] = [ws.count()]
  else:
    words[ws].append(ws.count())
```

it is obviously not `count` that I use here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is dedicated class named `collections.Counter` to perform such tasks:

```
import collections
words = "hey hey hello"
c = collections.Counter(words.split())
print c  # Counter({'hey': 2, 'hello': 1})
```

Explicit solution would be something like this:

```
wordsCount = {}
words = []  # list of words
for word in words:
  if word not in wordsCount:
    wordsCount[word] = 0
  wordsCount[word] += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
w = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'd', 'c']

words = {}
for ws in w:
    if ws not in words:
        words[ws] = 1
    else:
        words[ws] += 1

print (words)
```

The output is `{'c': 2, 'a': 1, 'd': 1, 'b': 2}`.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this:

```
s="There is a jungle nearby our house.We need to go for a walk in jungle"
d={}
sp=s.split(' ')
for item in sp:
    count=sp.count(item)
    d.update({item:count})
print d
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/350567) by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.